# Prisma Client Validation Error with Next Auth.js

Tags: javascript, next.js, psql, prisma, next-auth

I get this error when working with Next Authentication with the google adapter.

```
✓ Compiled /api/auth/[...nextauth] in 371ms (70 modules)
(node:9269) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
[next-auth][error][adapter_error_getUserByAccount] 
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#adapter_error_getuserbyaccount 
Invalid `p.account.findUnique()` invocation in
/Users/ASUS/outsidetest4/node_modules/@next-auth/prisma-adapter/dist/index.js:211:45

 208 getUserByEmail: (email) => p.user.findUnique({ where: { email } }),
  209 async getUserByAccount(provider_providerAccountId) {
  210     var _a;
→ 211     const account = await p.account.findUnique({
            where: {
              provider_providerAccountId: {
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                providerAccountId: "104357183920961836781",
                provider: "google"
              },
          ?   id?: Int,
          ?   AND?: AccountWhereInput | AccountWhereInput[],
          ?   OR?: AccountWhereInput[],
          ?   NOT?: AccountWhereInput | AccountWhereInput[],
          ?   userId?: IntNullableFilter | Int | Null,
          ?   provider?: StringFilter | String,
          ?   providerId?: StringFilter | String,
          ?   providerAccountId?: StringFilter | String,
          ?   refreshToken?: StringNullableFilter | String | Null,
          ?   accessToken?: StringNullableFilter | String | Null,
          ?   accessTokenExpires?: DateTimeNullableFilter | DateTime | Null,
          ?   createdAt?: DateTimeFilter | DateTime,
          ?   updatedAt?: DateTimeFilter | DateTime,
          ?   user?: UserNullableRelationFilter | UserWhereInput | Null
            },
            select: {
              user: true
            }
          })

Unknown argument `provider_providerAccountId`. Available options are marked with ?. {
  message: '\n' +
    'Invalid `p.account.findUnique()` invocation in\n' +
    '/Users/ASUS/outsidetest4/node_modules/@next-auth/prisma-adapter/dist/index.js:211:45\n' +
    '\n' +
    '  208 getUserByEmail: (email) => p.user.findUnique({ where: { email } }),\n' +
    '  209 async getUserByAccount(provider_providerAccountId) {\n' +
    '  210     var _a;\n' +
    '→ 211     const account = await p.account.findUnique({\n' +
    '            where: {\n' +
    '              provider_providerAccountId: {\n' +
    '              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n' +
    '                providerAccountId: "104357183920961836781",\n' +
    '                provider: "google"\n' +
    '              },\n' +
    '          ?   id?: Int,\n' +
    '          ?   AND?: AccountWhereInput | AccountWhereInput[],\n' +
    '          ?   OR?: AccountWhereInput[],\n' +
    '          ?   NOT?: AccountWhereInput | AccountWhereInput[],\n' +
    '          ?   userId?: IntNullableFilter | Int | Null,\n' +
    '          ?   provider?: StringFilter | String,\n' +
    '          ?   providerId?: StringFilter | String,\n' +
    '          ?   providerAccountId?: StringFilter | String,\n' +
    '          ?   refreshToken?: StringNullableFilter | String | Null,\n' +
    '          ?   accessToken?: StringNullableFilter | String | Null,\n' +
    '          ?   accessTokenExpires?: DateTimeNullableFilter | DateTime | Null,\n' +
    '          ?   createdAt?: DateTimeFilter | DateTime,\n' +
    '          ?   updatedAt?: DateTimeFilter | DateTime,\n' +
    '          ?   user?: UserNullableRelationFilter | UserWhereInput | Null\n' +
    '            },\n' +
    '            select: {\n' +
    '              user: true\n' +
    '            }\n' +
    '          })\n' +
    '\n' +
    'Unknown argument `provider_providerAccountId`. Available options are marked with ?.',
  stack: 'PrismaClientValidationError: \n' +
    'Invalid `p.account.findUnique()` invocation in\n' +
    '/Users/ASUS/outsidetest4/node_modules/@next-auth/prisma-adapter/dist/index.js:211:45\n' +
    '\n' +
    '  208 getUserByEmail: (email) => p.user.findUnique({ where: { email } }),\n' +
    '  209 async getUserByAccount(provider_providerAccountId) {\n' +
    '  210     var _a;\n' +
    '→ 211     const account = await p.account.findUnique({\n' +
    '            where: {\n' +
    '              provider_providerAccountId: {\n' +
    '              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n' +
    '                providerAccountId: "104357183920961836781",\n' +
    '                provider: "google"\n' +
    '              },\n' +
    '          ?   id?: Int,\n' +
    '          ?   AND?: AccountWhereInput | AccountWhereInput[],\n' +
    '          ?   OR?: AccountWhereInput[],\n' +
    '          ?   NOT?: AccountWhereInput | AccountWhereInput[],\n' +
    '          ?   userId?: IntNullableFilter | Int | Null,\n' +
    '          ?   provider?: StringFilter | String,\n' +
    '          ?   providerId?: StringFilter | String,\n' +
    '          ?   providerAccountId?: StringFilter | String,\n' +
    '          ?   refreshToken?: StringNullableFilter | String | Null,\n' +
    '          ?   accessToken?: StringNullableFilter | String | Null,\n' +
    '          ?   accessTokenExpires?: DateTimeNullableFilter | DateTime | Null,\n' +
    '          ?   createdAt?: DateTimeFilter | DateTime,\n' +
    '          ?   updatedAt?: DateTimeFilter | DateTime,\n' +
    '          ?   user?: UserNullableRelationFilter | UserWhereInput | Null\n' +
    '            },\n' +
    '            select: {\n' +
    '              user: true\n' +
    '            }\n' +
    '          })\n' +
    '\n' +
    'Unknown argument `provider_providerAccountId`. Available options are marked with ?.\n' +
    '    at ti (/Users/ASUS/outsidetest4/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:118:5888)\n' +
    '    at si.handleRequestError (/Users/ASUS/outsidetest4/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:125:6473)\n' +
    '    at si.handleAndLogRequestError (/Users/ASUS/outsidetest4/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:125:6151)\n' +
    '    at si.request (/Users/ASUS/outsidetest4/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:125:5859)\n' +
    '    at async l (/Users/ASUS/outsidetest4/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:130:10025)\n' +
    '    at async getUserByAccount (/Users/ASUS/outsidetest4/node_modules/@next-auth/prisma-adapter/dist/index.js:211:29)',
  name: 'PrismaClientValidationError'
}
[next-auth][error][OAUTH_CALLBACK_HANDLER_ERROR] 
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#oauth_callback_handler_error 
Invalid `p.account.findUnique()` invocation in
/Users/ASUS/outsidetest4/node_modules/@next-auth/prisma-adapter/dist/index.js:211:45

  208 getUserByEmail: (email) => p.user.findUnique({ where: { email } }),
  209 async getUserByAccount(provider_providerAccountId) {
  210     var _a;
→ 211     const account = await p.account.findUnique({
            where: {
              provider_providerAccountId: {
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                providerAccountId: "104357183920961836781",
                provider: "google"
              },
          ?   id?: Int,
          ?   AND?: AccountWhereInput | AccountWhereInput[],
          ?   OR?: AccountWhereInput[],
          ?   NOT?: AccountWhereInput | AccountWhereInput[],
          ?   userId?: IntNullableFilter | Int | Null,
          ?   provider?: StringFilter | String,
          ?   providerId?: StringFilter | String,
          ?   providerAccountId?: StringFilter | String,
          ?   refreshToken?: StringNullableFilter | String | Null,
          ?   accessToken?: StringNullableFilter | String | Null,
          ?   accessTokenExpires?: DateTimeNullableFilter | DateTime | Null,
          ?   createdAt?: DateTimeFilter | DateTime,
          ?   updatedAt?: DateTimeFilter | DateTime,
          ?   user?: UserNullableRelationFilter | UserWhereInput | Null
            },
            select: {
              user: true
            }
          })

Unknown argument `provider_providerAccountId`. Available options are marked with ?. PrismaClientValidationError: 
Invalid `p.account.findUnique()` invocation in
/Users/ASUS/outsidetest4/node_modules/@next-auth/prisma-adapter/dist/index.js:211:45

  208 getUserByEmail: (email) => p.user.findUnique({ where: { email } }),
  209 async getUserByAccount(provider_providerAccountId) {
  210     var _a;
→ 211     const account = await p.account.findUnique({
            where: {
              provider_providerAccountId: {
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                providerAccountId: "104357183920961836781",
                provider: "google"
              },
          ?   id?: Int,
          ?   AND?: AccountWhereInput | AccountWhereInput[],
          ?   OR?: AccountWhereInput[],
          ?   NOT?: AccountWhereInput | AccountWhereInput[],
          ?   userId?: IntNullableFilter | Int | Null,
          ?   provider?: StringFilter | String,
          ?   providerId?: StringFilter | String,
          ?   providerAccountId?: StringFilter | String,
          ?   refreshToken?: StringNullableFilter | String | Null,
          ?   accessToken?: StringNullableFilter | String | Null,
          ?   accessTokenExpires?: DateTimeNullableFilter | DateTime | Null,
          ?   createdAt?: DateTimeFilter | DateTime,
          ?   updatedAt?: DateTimeFilter | DateTime,
          ?   user?: UserNullableRelationFilter | UserWhereInput | Null
            },
            select: {
              user: true
            }
          })

Unknown argument `provider_providerAccountId`. Available options are marked with ?.
    at ti (/Users/ASUS/outsidetest4/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:118:5888)
    at si.handleRequestError (/Users/ASUS/outsidetest4/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:125:6473)
    at si.handleAndLogRequestError (/Users/ASUS/outsidetest4/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:125:6151)
    at si.request (/Users/ASUS/outsidetest4/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:125:5859)
    at async l (/Users/ASUS/outsidetest4/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:130:10025)
    at async getUserByAccount (/Users/ASUS/outsidetest4/node_modules/@next-auth/prisma-adapter/dist/index.js:211:29) {
  name: 'GetUserByAccountError',
  code: undefined
}
```

This is how my schema looks like:

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider  = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model User {
  id                 Int                 @id @unique @default(autoincrement())
  firstName          String
  lastName           String
  email              String              @unique
  username           String              @unique
  password           String
  image              String?
  role               UserRole            @default(NORMAL)
  emailVerified      DateTime?
  sessions           Session[]           @relation("Session_user")
  accounts           Account[]           @relation("Account_user")
  verificationTokens VerificationToken[] // If you want to associate multiple verification tokens with a user
  listings           Listing[]           @relation("Listing_user")
  bookings           Booking[]           @relation("Booking_user")
  likes              Like[]              @relation("Like_user")
  searches           Search[]            @relation("Search_user")
  createdAt          DateTime            @default(now())
  updatedAt          DateTime            @updatedAt
}

enum UserRole {
  NORMAL
  ALPHA
}

model Category {
  id        Int       @id @unique @default(autoincrement())
  name      String
  listings  Listing[]
  createdAt DateTime  @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime  @updatedAt
}

model Listing {
  id            Int          @id @unique @default(autoincrement())
  name          String
  host          User         @relation("Listing_user", fields: [hostId], references: [id])
  hostId        Int
  images        String[]
  shortCaption  String
  description   String
  price         Decimal
  startDate     DateTime
  endDate       DateTime
  location      String
  coordinates   Coordinates? @relation(fields: [coordinatesId], references: [id])
  likes         Like[]       @relation("Like_listing")
  bookings      Booking[]    @relation("Booking_listing")
  coordinatesId Int?
  categories    Category[]
  createdAt     DateTime     @default(now())
  updatedAt     DateTime     @updatedAt
  Approved      Boolean
}

model Like {
  id        Int      @id @unique @default(autoincrement())
  user      User     @relation("Like_user", fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId    Int
  listing   Listing  @relation("Like_listing", fields: [listingId], references: [id])
  listingId Int
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
}

model Booking {
  id        Int      @id @unique @default(autoincrement())
  user      User     @relation("Booking_user", fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId    Int
  listing   Listing  @relation("Booking_listing", fields: [listingId], references: [id])
  listingId Int
  request   String?
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
}

model Search {
  id        Int      @id @unique @default(autoincrement())
  keyword   String
  timestamp DateTime @default(now())
  user      User?    @relation("Search_user", fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId    Int?
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
}

model Coordinates {
  id        Int       @id @unique @default(autoincrement())
  name      String
  latitude  Float
  longitude Float
  listingId Int
  listings  Listing[] @relation
  createdAt DateTime  @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime  @updatedAt
}

model Session {
  id           Int      @id @unique @default(autoincrement())
  sessionToken String   @unique
  userId       Int?
  expires      DateTime
  user         User?    @relation("Session_user", fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  createdAt    DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt    DateTime @updatedAt
}

model Account {
  id                 Int       @id @unique @default(autoincrement())
  userId             Int?
  provider           String
  providerId         String
  providerAccountId  String
  refreshToken       String?
  accessToken        String?
  accessTokenExpires DateTime?
  createdAt          DateTime  @default(now())
  updatedAt          DateTime  @updatedAt
  user               User?     @relation("Account_user", fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
}

model VerificationToken {
  id         Int      @id @unique @default(autoincrement())
  identifier String
  token      String   @unique
  expires    DateTime
  userId     Int // Assuming each verification token is associated with a user
  user       User     @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  createdAt  DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt  DateTime @updatedAt

  @@unique([identifier, token])
}
```

I have scouted the internet for fixes, but nothing seems to be working

I have tried to update my model, still nothing. I am using Next.js and Prisma to communicate with my database and front end.

My configuration file looks like this:

```
// import { PrismaAdapter } from '@next-auth/prisma-adapter';
// import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';
// import NextAuth from "next-auth";
// import EmailProvider from "next-auth/providers/email";
// import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";

// const prisma = new PrismaClient();

// export default NextAuth({
//   adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
//   providers: [
//     GoogleProvider({
//       clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
//       clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
//       authorization: {
//         params: {
//           prompt: "consent",
//           access_type: "offline",
//           response_type: "code"
//         }
//       },
//       profile(profile) {
//         return {
//           id: profile.sub,
//           name: profile.name || profile.login,
//           email: profile.email,
//           image: profile.avatar_url,
//         };
//       },
//     }),
//     EmailProvider({
//       server: {
//         host: process.env.EMAIL_SERVER_HOST,
//         port: process.env.EMAIL_SERVER_PORT,
//         auth: {
//           user: process.env.EMAIL_SERVER_USER,
//           pass: process.env.EMAIL_SERVER_PASSWORD,
//         },
//       },
//       from: process.env.EMAIL_FROM,
//       maxAge: 10 * 60 * 60,
//       profile(profile) {
//         return {
//           name: profile.name || profile.login,
//           email: profile.email,
//           image: profile.avatar_url,
//         };
//       },
//     }),
//   ],
//   callbacks: {
//     async signIn({ account, profile, isNewUser }) {
//       if (account.provider === 'google') {
//         const existingAccount = await prisma.account.findUnique({
//           where: {
//             providerAccountId: profile.sub,  // Change this to the correct field name
            
//             providerType: 'google',
//           },
//           select: {
//             user: true,
//           },
//         });

//         // If the account exists, you might want to update it or perform additional checks
//         if (existingAccount) {
//           // Do something with the existing account
//         }

//         // If it's a new user, create an entry in your database
//         if (isNewUser) {
//           await prisma.user.create({
//             data: {
//               id: profile.sub,  // Change this to the correct field name
//               email: profile.email,
//               firstName: profile.given_name || '',
//               lastName: profile.family_name || '',
//               username: profile.given_name + "_username", // Change this to the appropriate field from the profile
//               password: 'a_default_password', // Change this to the appropriate field from the profile
//               image: profile.picture,
//               // Add other fields as needed
//             },
//           });
//         }

//         // Return true if the user should be allowed to sign in
//         return true;
//       }
//       return true; // Do different verification for other providers that don't have `email_verified`
//     },
//   },
// });

import NextAuth from 'next-auth'
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'

import { PrismaAdapter } from '@next-auth/prisma-adapter';

import EmailProvider from "next-auth/providers/email";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";


const prisma = new PrismaClient()

export default NextAuth({
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
      authorization: {
        params: {
          prompt: "consent",
          access_type: "offline",
          response_type: "code"
        }
      },
      profile(profile) {
        return {
          id: profile.sub,
          name: profile.name || profile.login,
          email: profile.email,
          image: profile.avatar_url,
        };
      },
    }),
    EmailProvider({
      server: {
        host: process.env.EMAIL_SERVER_HOST,
        port: process.env.EMAIL_SERVER_PORT,
        auth: {
          user: process.env.EMAIL_SERVER_USER,
          pass: process.env.EMAIL_SERVER_PASSWORD,
        },
      },
      from: process.env.EMAIL_FROM,
      maxAge: 10 * 60 * 60,
      profile(profile) {
        return {
          name: profile.name || profile.login,
          email: profile.email,
          image: profile.avatar_url,
        };
      },
    }),
  ],
  
  callbacks: {
    async session(session, user) {
      session.userId = user.id;
      return session;
    },
    async jwt(token, user, account, profile, isNewUser) {
      if (user) {
        token.id = user.id;
      }
      return token;
    },
  },
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you did not migrate

```
 npx prisma migrate dev
```

if that does not work

```
npx prisma migrate dev --name "findunique"
```